# how to differentiate error's source based on stage in Promise chain

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have 2 callback that both call API and return `Promise`. They should go sequentially. Let's name them `verifyThing` and `updateThing`.

So without error handling it would be as easy as

```
verifyThing()
 .then((id) => updateThing(id))
```

But now error handling comes. Suppose I need to display different error message once `verifyThing` fails or `updateThing`. Also obviously I don't need to call `updateThing` if `verifyThing` fails.

So far I've tried with custom Error:

```
class VerifyError extends Error {};
verifyThing()
  .catch(e => {
    message("cannot verify");
    throw new VerifyError();
  })
 .then((id) => updateThing(id))
 .catch(e => {
   if (e instanceof VerifyError) return;
   message("cannot update");
 })
```

Unfortunately custom Error [check does not work](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4485) with Babel 6.26 we use. As a dirty patch I can throw magic string instead of Error subclass, but ESLint rules are for a reason, right?

So finally I have got working variant. But I believe it has worse readability(because of nesting):

```
verifyThing()
 .catch(e => {
    message("cannot verify");
    throw e;
  })
 .then((id) => 
   updateThing(id)
     .catch(e => {
       message("cannot update");
     })
 )
```

Is there any other way to handle all the logic in the same chain?

Comment: Why not just throw a native Error of the appropriate subtype (or just of Error itself), rather than extending?

Comment: In your last example, `id` can be `undefined`. Is that really want you want? _I don't need to call `updateThing` if `verifyThing` fails._ In other words, your last example _does_ call `updateThing` even when `verifyThing` fails.

Comment: oh, yes, you're right. trying to provide some minimal example I've lost `throw`. fixed.

Comment: what do you mean `Error of appropriate subtype`?

Comment: a classic thing to do is to store the id on the subclassed error. Instead of checking by instance, you check by id. This allows btw to avoid subclassing n times for how many errors you have

Comment: @grodzi could you make answer with example? I like how it sounds but I've never used such a strategy, so not sure if I understand it well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the actual behavior you want can be achieved by reordering your last example:

```
verifyThing().then(id => 
  updateThing(id).catch(e => {
    message("cannot update");
  })
).catch(e => {
  message("cannot verify");
})
```

The outer `catch()` will only catch errors from `verifyThing()` since errors from `updateThing(id)` have been handled by the inner `catch()`. In addition, you're always left with a resolved promise instead of a rejected one, which is appropriate since both types of errors have been handled already.

To avoid the appearance that error handling is not close to the source, move the inner portion to a helper function:

```
function tryUpdateThing (id) {
  return updateThing(id).catch(e => {
    message("cannot update");
  });
}

verifyThing().then(
  tryUpdateThing
).catch(e => {
  message("cannot verify");
});
```

Whether or not this is acceptably readable, I'll leave up to you to decide.

Comment: Thanks for sample. My fault, my last code sample missed `throw` so did not work as required. Actually, I'd like to avoid nested `.then()`/`.catch()` if possible and keep error handling as close as possible to error source. what do you think?

Comment: @skyboyer the error handling _is_ as close as possible to the source. It's more obvious though when you move `updateThing(id).catch(e => {
    message("cannot update");
  })` to a helper function.

Comment: @skyboyer The nested `catch` looks unfortunate but I think it's the best way to handle this sort of thing (`message` better never throw, right?)

Comment: yes, also thanks for idea to encapsulate call+`catch` into named `try...` function. looks (almost) ideal.

Answer (score 2):

If `async/await` is an option, then:

```
async function() {
    let id;
    try {
        id = await verifyThing();
        await updateThing(id);
    } catch(e) {
        message(id === undefined ? "cannot verify" : "cannot update");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This assumes that when `verifyThing()` fulfills, it will resolve with a defined value.

Comment: totally makes sense. to scale that for more steps I probably may introduce additional variable `errorMessageToShowIfFailOnNextStep`, so in `catch()` I would have relevant error message even without `if/else`. thanks!